# Slow old notebook Hardy => Karmic

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-8.04

i have one very slow notebook from year about 2000. On the computer is running icewm with firefox (in this times chromium for testing). **My question is if it's good step to upgrade the system to Karmic Koala?** I can't install another OS on that. It doesn't have CD-ROM, it can't boot from flash, or network.

The new wanted state is little bit faster system for browsing web and copying photos to local NAS.

I don't mention hardware configuration, becouse it's real speed is really deep below the paper parameters.

Comment: if it can go online, you could bootstrap another install from unetbootin

Comment: If you want to add a cd rom drive: I found it is easy to exchange cd rom drives between old laptops, the drives all have the same connectors, but it is necessary to exchange the adapter which is normally attached to the cd rom connector with a small screwdriver. I do this all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you're looking at the basics -- the kernel, X.org, etc -- an upgrade will be fine.

If you're talking about a full-blown GNOME/KDE desktop, upgrading won't help you and may be very detrimental.

If you're dependent on this system for anything important, it may be better to stick with Hardy LTS for a while longer.

Comment: Yes the system runs only gdm, X, IceWM, Totem/MPlayer, OpenOffice and Firefox/Chromium. (Chromium works fine on that machine). Gnome is running only in barbecue time;)

What does mean the last paragraph? Is it about the upgrade could not pass well? The computer is my father's kinda webbrowserbook.

Comment: yeah, you could have trouble with the upgrade.  __make backups__ if your father has any important docs or things he's saved from the web.  if you get into trouble and need to fresh-install, you can probably move the harddrive to another system to install from CD.

Answer (score 0):

a 9 year old laptop is hardly 'Ubuntu material'

try something 'leightweight', such as **[MacPup Opera or Foxy](http://macpup.org/)** (based on Puppy) or **[DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)**.

Comment: The question is not what put there, but is it good move to ugprade? But thank you for new options. If find out how to put there something different, ill discover these.

Comment: well, i don't think "it's good step to upgrade" a 9 years old laptop "to carmic coala" (thought 9.10 is at the letter K now, Karmic Koala?), it will be slow as molasses, certainly not faster than with Hardy Heron.

Comment: you'd be right if it was Windows, molly, but i don't think Ubuntu's automatically slower.  (stock install, maybe.  but it doesn't sound like he's running a full-blown gnome-desktop.)

Comment: (you're right about the letter K tho.  i almost ignored this question because i thought it was soda related ... "carmic cola" hah!)

Comment: that'd be the first soda-related Ubuntu :)

Comment: One hopes that two more versions will net us "Mountainous Dew" :-)

Comment: it won't.  "Mountainous MrPibb" maybe...